# CDN caching for React.JS SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, server-side-rendering

I have the below code to do my server-side rending:

```
// Load in our HTML file from our build
fs.readFile(
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/index.html'),
  'utf8',
  (err, htmlData) => {
    // If there's an error... serve up something nasty
    ...
    // Pass all this nonsense into our HTML formatting function above
    const html = injectHTML(htmlData, {
      html: helmet.htmlAttributes.toString(),
      title: helmet.title.toString(),
      meta: helmet.meta.toString(),
      headScript: helmet.script.toString(),
      link: helmet.link.toString(),
      body: routeMarkup,
      scripts: extraChunks,
      state: JSON.stringify(store.getState()).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')
    });
    // We have all the final HTML, let's send it to the user already!
    res.send(html);
```

It is working fine. However, all my static assets are loaded from `../build`. I want to connect a CDN, such as S3 to cache assets.

To do this, I need to prepend the CDN url to links to static assets so `<script src="/static/js/main.7e3b844f.chunk.js"></script>` becomes `<script src="https://cdn.mydomain.com/static/js/main.7e3b844f.chunk.js"></script>`

The urls of interest are inside `htmlData`. I could use regular expressions to replace `/static/css` with `${prefix}/static/css` and the same for `/static/js`.

Are there better alternatives than running a regex? Suggestoins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended-up doing the below before injecting HTML with body, meta etc:

```
const prefix =
  process.env.REACT_APP_STAGE === 'production'
    ? 'https://prod-cdn.mydomain.com'
    : '';
const processedHtmlData = htmlData.replace(
  /(\/static)/g,
  `${prefix}$1`
);
const html = injectHTML(processedHtmlData, {
  html: helmet.htmlAttributes.toString(),
  title: helmet.title.toString(),
  meta: helmet.meta.toString(),
  headScript: helmet.script.toString(),
  link: helmet.link.toString(),
  body: routeMarkup,
  scripts: extraChunks,
  state: JSON.stringify(store.getState()).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')
});
```

It works.